# Lotus sorting view on orderdate does not work properly

Tags: sorting, lotusscript, lotus

I have created a view in which I also have a column which holds dates. This column can be sorted on ascending and descending. This is my column properties value:

[image]

But the problem is that the view does not sort the dates properly:

[image]

And here a screenshot of the orderdate field itself:

[image]

And here screenshot of the document with the orderdate that is out of order in the view:

[image]

**Update**

Some documents had the orderdate as text instead of date.. I create these documents through a java agent. The field orderdate I fill in like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatterDatumForField=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
docOrder.replaceItemValue("Orderdatum",formatterDatumForField.format(currentDateForField));
```

But it is saved as text instead of date. Anyone knows why?

Comment: is your orderdate really a date? Show the properties of one of the documents that shows the item that you use in the view

Comment: Please show the same screenshot from the first document that is "out of order" (19-12-2016)

Comment: Ok I update my question again

Comment: @bboni Is it first column in a view?

Comment: @bboni it could be related to sorting in first column. What happens if you click on column header to get documents sorted (does it work then?)?

Comment: Yes the first column can be sorted ascending and this works properly

Comment: There are in total 10 column headers in the view and every one can be sorted

Comment: if the first column is sorted, then the second column will follow sorting of first column.
Try to set Date column as a 1-st - it will work as you expected (most likely)

Comment: Still the same problem if i set date column header as 1st

Comment: Make us an example and let us see the database :)

Comment: ok that gonna be difficult i think i just use this set up no problemo

Comment: Have you tried going to the fourth tab in the column properties dialog and changing the selection for Style from "General" to "Date"?

Comment: Are the values in all the documents dates?  Or are some dates and some strings?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz yes tried and still not working.

Comment: @Duston And Duston You are right some of the documents had text as orderdates. I updated my question.

Comment: It's saved as text because when you save a value from the back end you have to explicitly tell the item that it's a Date/Time.  (No, it doesn't matter how it's defined on the form.)  It seems you do that by setting the DateTimeValue property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that orderdate field was set by a backend agent and this field was set with a string.

I know saved the current time as a DateTime object and now it works:

```
 DateTime timenow = session.createDateTime("Today");
 timenow.setNow();

 docOrder.replaceItemValue("Orderdatum",  timenow);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why it's not working for you, but you can brute force it with something like this in the column formula

```
dateForSure := @TextToTime(OrderDatum);
@Text(@Year(dateForSure)) + "-" + @Text(@Month(dateForSure)) + "-" + @Text(@Day(dateForSure));
```

Also: your Java code saves a text value because the format() method of SimpleDateFormat returns a StringBuffer. The ReplaceItemValue method generates a text item when its input is a String or StringBuffer. Assuming your form defines OrderDatum as a Time/Date field, you can call Document.ComputeWithForm in your code to force it to convert the text item to a Time/Date. Another method - probably preferable given the potential side-effects of calling ComputeWithForm would be to create a DateTime object in your Java code and pass it to the ReplaceItemValue method instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `formatterDatumForField.format(currentDateForField)` returns a String instead of a date/time value. Assuming that currentDateForField is a date/time value, you should change

```
SimpleDateFormat formatterDatumForField=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
docOrder.replaceItemValue("Orderdatum",formatterDatumForField.format(currentDateForField));
```

to

```
docOrder.replaceItemValue("Orderdatum",currentDateForField);
```